# foreach loop in Laravel Forge scheduler not working

Tags: php, laravel, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

I have a Laravel app running on Laravel Forge with Digital Ocean and I need to send a daily email to some of my app´s users, but foreach loop inside $schedule closure does not recognize the $user instance.

Here's the schedule function inside Kernel.php:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

    $users = collect();
    $users->push(User::find(1));
    $users->push(User::find(544));

    $schedule->call(function () use ($users) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            Mail::to($user->email)->send(new BoltraNuevoUsuario($user, 'nuevoUsuario'));
        }
    })->dailyAt('8:00');
}
```

I dd($users) inside the closure's foreach and the collection is correct, showing both prefetched users; but $user is null, no matter what I do. I've already tried setting php´s register_argc_argv value to On in both PHP FPM Configuration and PHP CLI Configuration files via Forge, but it didn´t help. I´ve also tried with the following Cron jobs sentences:

Sentence 1:

```
    php /home/forge/www.boltra.com.mx/artisan schedule:run
```

```
    Running scheduled command: Closure
    In Kernel.php line 43:
      Trying to get property 'email' of non-object
```

Sentence 2:

```
    php /home/forge/www.boltra.com.mx/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

```
    Running scheduled command: Closure
    In Kernel.php line 43:
      Trying to get property 'email' of non-object
```

Sentence 3:

```
    php-cli -q /home/forge/www.boltra.com.mx/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

```
    Command: php-cli -q /home/forge/www.boltra.com.mx/artisan schedule:run >> 
    /dev/null 2>&1
    /bin/sh: 1: php-cli: not found
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: P.S. In local environment the same job works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: is there actually a `User` on this other system with `id = 1` and one with `id = 544`? if not those would end up being `null`s

Comment: Hi. Yes @lagbox. They are there, both locally and on production server. It´s very strange, because like I said, if you dd($users) while inside the foreach loop, they both show up, but if you dd($user), it shows as null.

Comment: @lagbox. You are absolutely right. I had softdeleted user(1) during previous tests, and forgot to un-delete it.  Sorry for taking your time  :(